# Switch from fs-promise to fs-extra

Tags: node.js, react-native

I try to install create-react-native-app package and i got this warning:

```
npm install -g create-react-native-app
npm WARN deprecated fs-promise@1.0.0: Use mz or fs-extra^3.0 with Promise Support
```

Then I have tried to install fs-extra, and retry an installation of create-react-native-app package:

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-native-app
npm install -g fs-extra
npm install -g create-react-native-app
```

But I still got the same warning, any clue to solve this?

Thx,

Orb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to safely ignore the warning. The warning you see is because react-native is using a deprecated package (`fs-promise`).